# How do I remove a film from my "watchlist" on letterboxd?

Tags: letterboxd

A while ago I added a film to my letterboxd watchlist (those films I want to watch but for whatever reason haven't).

However, when it came on TV recently I watched the first 20 minutes and realised that it was a bad film and I turned over.

Now I want to remove the film from my watchlist, but I don't want to add to the lists of films I've seen (yes it was that bad). However, the only options I can see are to mark it as "seen"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to click through to the film page itself.

There there is a side bar and if you hover over the entry:

> This film is in your watchlist

it turns into:

> Remove from your watchlist

Click that and the film is gone

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to hover over the poster for one of the films, then click the 'three dots' icon to open the popup options menu. There is an option in that menu to remove a film from your watchlist.

Comment: I couldn't see an option there, hence this question.